# Django how to link tableCheckBoxColumn to DB entry

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have a model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    col_1 = model.CharField(max_length=20)
    col_2 = model.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...
```

and a table

```
class MyTable(table.Tables)
    enabled = tables.CheckBoxColumn(accessor='enabled')
    col_1 = tables.Column()
    col_2 = tables.Column()
    ...
```

In my view I later get the queryset as a dataframe, do stuff with them and render them

```
def index(request):

    context = dict()
    template = 'myindex/index.html'

    entries= MyModel.objects.all()
    df = dpd.read_frame(entries)
    ...
    do stuff with df
    ...
    context['my_table'] = MyTable(df.to_dict(orient='records'))

return render(request, template, context)
```

Which I then render

```
{% load django_tables2 %}
<html>
    <body>
        {% render_table table %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I am looking for a way to update the database when the checkboxes get clicked.
So far, the checkboxes dont even take the values from the database but are all unchecked.

Any pointers on what a good way is to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs on `CheckboxColumn`](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/columns/checkboxcolumn.py) have a pretty clear note on what to expect from it:

> You might expect that you could select multiple checkboxes in the rendered > table and then do something with that. This functionality is not implemented. If you want something to actually happen, you will need to implement that yourself.

So, if you manage to render them in a state corresponding to some db-value, you still need to implement any persistence of changed values.

Doing so would either require some custom JavaScript posting changes asynchronously to some endpoint you create, or wrapping the whole table in a form.